# How can I quickly disable a try statement in python for testing?

Tags: python, debugging, testing, exception

Say I have the following code:

```
try:
    print 'foo'
    # A lot more code...
    print 'bar'
except:
    pass
```

How would I for testing purposes disable the try-statement temporary?

You can't just comment the `try` and `except` lines out as the indention will still be off.

Isn't there any easier way than this?

```
#try:
print 'foo'
# A lot more code...
print 'bar'
#except:
#    pass
```

Comment: You should generally avoid having "A lot more code" inside a `try:` block in the first place.  Usually you want just one line in there.

Comment: This question makes no sense. You don't disable `try` statements for testing, you test whether it gets properly executed. If you mean testing as in some form of "prototyping", just move the code inside the try statement to a function and call the function directly.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could reraise the exception as the first line of your except block, which would behave just as it would without the try/except.

```
try:
    print 'foo'
    # A lot more code...
    print 'bar'
except:
    raise # was: pass
```

Answer (score 18):

Piggy-backing off of velotron's answer, I like the idea of doing something like this:

```
try:
    print 'foo'
    # A lot more code...
    print 'bar'
except:
    if settings.DEBUG:  # Use some boolean to represent dev state, such as DEBUG in Django
        raise           # Raise the error
    # Otherwise, handle and move on. 
    # Typically I want to log it rather than just pass.
    logger.exception("Something went wrong")
```

Answer (score 6):

Turn it into an `if True` statement, with the `except` clause 'commented out' by the `else` branch (which will never be executed):

```
if True: # try:
    # try suite statements
else: # except:
    # except suite statements
```

The `else:` is optional, you could also just comment out the whole `except:` suite, but by using `else:` you can leave the whole `except:` suite indented and uncommented.

So:

```
try:
    print 'foo'
    # A lot more code...
    print 'bar'
except SomeException as se:
    print 'Uhoh, got SomeException:', se.args[0]
```

becomes:

```
if True: # try:
    print 'foo'
    # A lot more code...
    print 'bar'
else: # except SomeException as se:
    print 'Uhoh, got SomeException:', se.args[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Make your `except` only catch something that the `try` block won't throw:

```
class FakeError:
    pass

try:
    # code
except FakeError: # OldError:
    # catch
```

Not actually sure if this is a good idea, but it does work!

Answer (score 0):

Xymostech's answer seems the best to me, such as with one word added to the code, the OP's request is satisfied.

BTW you have to declare the class this way :

```
class FakeError(Exception):
```